# Files Deleting from Table View but not from Document Directory by using Swipe Gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, document, swipe, gesture

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
         NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];       
         NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory
         stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[self->localSongs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];        
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil]; 
        [self->localSongs removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: is ur filepath coming rite ? nslog to find out

Comment: seems your filePath is incorrect then. NSError *error = nil; and pass ist in as error:&error; and check the output with NSLog(@"error: %@",error);

Comment: Ya rit. ifpath is wrong how iable to list songs in table view....

Comment: The same path i used to list songs.....localSongs=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains ( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *de = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory] ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is code for how to delete file from document Directory :

```
NSString *imageName = @"name of your file"
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName] error:nil];
```

Comment: I dont want to delete single files. i want to delete Multiples files one by one by Swipe gesture inside Document directory and subfolder inside document directory... plz help to resolve it

Comment: Dude its not working....   localSongs=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains ( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *de = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory] ;                                     // I m fetching my local songs by above methods inside document directory and subfolder inside it...

Comment: check you file name is proper or not ?

Comment: its deleting all files in document directory including sqlite files also but i want to delete particular files which is listed in table view by swipe gesture.....

Comment: when you swipe any cell, get file name that included on swiped cell...such like NSString *fileName = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPathe.row];... here you can get file name from swiped cell. and use this name in my code .. thanks :)

Comment: @Immi- may be you can ask Question on StackOverFlow :)